# WordPress URL Keeps Adding unnecessary Parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting

Anytime I open my client's website, the URL keeps on adding an unnecessary parameter

Example:

Website URL => https://example.com/

While loading, the URL will change into this

https://example.com/QKYUZ/YenNS/RQlKZ/QYSQc/SnSfZ/ljLWX/

or when login at the back office...

https://example.com/wp-admin/  =>  https://example.com/QYSQc/wp-admin/

I'm using WordPress, that happens either on the website or at the back office. Sometimes it will show different errors because of those.

Does anyone know what is happening or how can I fix this?

Comment: No, I can't remember when this started.

Comment: check `.htaccess` file( or provide it in your question )

Comment: it seems fine to me. Here is the file:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 1):

This is not the normal behaviour of WordPress. My first guess is, you have a plugin that's acting funny. I suggest you do the following;

1. Make a local copy of your website and set up using a local server and a database.
2. Once the site is up and running locally, go to plugins and deactivate all plugins. Re-enable them one after the other and you should find the culprit plugin.

This should help you resolve the issue.

Comment: I did that but somehow even if I di activate all the plugins and theme, it is still the same. Are there other ways that I can fix this?

Comment: Did you buy the theme? Try installing a fresh copy of the theme in a new WordPress instance. Also which WordPress version are you running?

Comment: No, the theme I'm using is free (Twenty Seventeen). Most of my client's other websites have the same theme (which are all running fine). The Wordpress version is 4.9.8.